# Android intent to open default file explorer overrides the folder path provided in intent.setData()

Tags: android

I am trying to open the default android file explorer through my app by firing an intent and setting the data to the desired folder location, but android always opens the explorer with the recently visited path as the folder location even with the flags to not maintain history enabled. Are there specific combinations of keys and flags to let android not proceed to opening the last visited folder?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+Constants.PATH + "/Reports"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
intent.setType(Constants.FILE_CHOOSER_MIME_TYPE_CONSTANT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Comment: Show your code to begin with. And what you want is not possible. Further there is no default file explorer under Android.

Comment: @greenapps when i fire the intent, the explorer opens with the list of files. I figured that must a default one.

Comment: Besides that what you want is not possible your approach is wrong too.  ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT will deliver you a content scheme. So if you want to set a path then using a file scheme makes no sense. You should have used a content scheme for setData(). But again: not possible what you want.

Comment: `even with the flags to not maintain history enabled` ???

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not open a "default file explorer". It opens a content chooser UI, where that content may or may not come from files on the filesystem. For example, it might come from Google Drive or a Windows server.

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not take a `Uri` as input. You cannot tell `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` what to show.

Comment: does ACTION_GET_CONTENT serve the purpose? I need a file picker UI which navigates to the folder i specify in the data part

Comment: @Sur: "does ACTION_GET_CONTENT serve the purpose?" -- no. "I need a file picker UI which navigates to the folder i specify in the data part" -- find [a library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) that meets your needs.